# Windows 10, Rename all *.jpg files in all subdirectories, with number starting from 1

Tags: powershell, recursion, batch-rename

I want a solution for the same problem, but in **Windows 10**.
[Recursively rename .jpg files in all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378365/recursively-rename-jpg-files-in-all-subdirectories)

I tried with following powershell command, 
`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.jpg | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D1}.jpg' -f $i++)}`

but it renames the files in sequential order without resetting the index to 1 in every sub folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two separate `Get-ChildItem` cmdlets for this. The first will gather all subdirectories and when looping though that, the second will gather the files in each directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\RootFolder\where\the\files\are' -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $count = 1   # reset the counter for this subdir to 1
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.jpg' -File | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:D1}.jpg' -f $count++) -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` if you are satisfied with the results shown in the console.

<sup>P.S. the title says `*.png`, but your code deals with `*.jpg`. Doesn't matter, as long as you set your filter to the correct extension and adjust the new name in the code accordingly</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As of my knowledge you have to do use it as a nested foreach:

```
Foreach ($directory in (Get-ChildItem -Directory)){
     $i = 1
     Get-ChildItem $directory.Fullname -Recurse -Include *.jpg | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D1}.jpg' -f $i++)}
}
```

I tested it and it worked :)
If it worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The OP is already using a foreach, so shouldn't the statement will be a nested foreach?

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand your comment. What is the OP? And is it a problem that the foreach is nested?

Comment: Don't take serious just edit the answer and use the word 'nested foreach' at the first line.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. Next time you can also purpose an edit ;)

Comment: This however will only reset the counter for each **first level** subdirectory. Using this, the counter will keep being incremented for every subsequent subdirectory. You apparently did not test this with multiple levels of directories. It is my understanding the OP wants the counter to be reset to `1` (not `0`) on **every** subfolder.

Comment: Yes exactly you're right. This works only for one level of subdirectories. Thanks for pointing this out